# find and check the last 4 characters in an edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am in the middle of improving my app. I am wondering if there is a way of checking the last 4 characters in an edittext against a string?

I wish to do this to ensure a file entered is of the correct extension.

Thank you, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the endsWith method, e.g.

```
if (s.endsWith(".jpg"))
```

Comment: This won't work for File.JPG You should use `if (s.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg"))` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

String.[subString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)(begin, end) function returns sub string.

You can do equals on that substring.

Example:

```
String last4Chars = text.subString(text.length()-4, text.length()); 

    if(last4Chars.equals(otherString))
    {
     //Last 4 characters are same.
     }
```

NOTE: Make sure String is not null && string length is greater than 4 before doing above operation, otherwise you may get exception.

Comment: How would I make it choose the last 4 characters, if I do not know the total length of the string?

Comment: You can use Strings length function to findout length of the string. Updated answer with sample code.

Comment: My app now force closes at this line: `last4chars = mFilePathTextView.getText().toString().substring(mFilePathTextView.getText().toString().length() -4, mFilePathTextView.getText().toString().length());`

Comment: Update with exception stack trace.